# ArrayList to Byte and vice versa

Tags: java, database, arraylist, type-conversion

Hi I need to store `ArrayList` in database of my project, for that I need some suggestion to  store `ArrayList` into DB by means of some techniques like ArrayList to Byte[] and store byte[] in DB and retreive my byte[] from DB and convert into my original `ArrayList` in Java

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're talking about Java's ArrayList (you didn't mention the language you have in mind).

In fact, there was a vary similar question: [Serializing Arraylists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11025187/serializing-arraylists)

Just serialize a list, and insert it to BLOB column. Then you can fetch it from DB and deserialize it.

**Edit:**

This is a piece of code you can use to serialize your ArrayList:

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try { 
        ObjectOutputStream ooStream = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
        ooStream.writeObject(myList);
        ooStream.close();
    } catch(IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } finally {
        try {
            baos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    byte[] serializedData = baos.toByteArray();
```

Having the data as byte[] you can now store it in bytea / BLOB column.

I hope this helps.